# oracle sql Col format numbers for all columns in specific table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a question, I want to format all the columns in the output of my selection not one by one

for example here is what i want to do:

this is my normal output:

```
name1 name 2 salary1 salary2 salary3 finances manager  senior_manager
----  ------ ------- ------  ------- -------- -------  -------------
3000  400000 8000000  90      99999  500000   4000000  900000000000
1000  100000 9000000  90      100000 900000   1000000  800000000000
4000  300000 7000000  90      99999  400200   1000000  500000000000
```

this is what i want to do:

```
name1 name 2 salary1 salary2 salary3 finances   manager  employee4
----  ------ ------- ------  ------- --------   -------  -------------
3,000  40,0000 8,000,000  90  99,999  500,000  4,000,000  9,000
1,000  10,0000 9,000,000  90  100,000 900,000  1,000,000  8,000
4,000  30,0000 7,000,000  90  99,999  400,200  1,000,000  5,000
```

So the solution is;

```
select name1, name2 , salary1, salary2, salary3, finances, manager, employee4 from database_table

col name1 format 999,999.99
col name2 format 999,999.99
col salary1 format 999,999.99
col Salary2 format 999,999.99
col Salary3 format 999,999.99
col Finances format 999,999.99
col Manager format 999,999.99
col Emlpoyee4 format 999,999.99

order by 1;
```

What i want to do: `col * format 999,999.99` or `col all_columns format 999,999.99`?

my question is, how to select all columns instead of one by one?

Comment: You can't. The formatting is done as part of the front end. In your case, it looks like you're using SQL\*Plus, and SQL\*Plus requires you to tell it how to format each column individually.

If you store your query in a script, you only need to write out the formatting once and then just run the script to output the results in your desired formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use SQL*Plus, then yes - there is a way to do it - use `SET NUMFORMAT`.

For example:

**Before**:

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 3000 name1, 400000 name2, 8000000 salary1, 90 salary2, 9999 salary3 from dual)
  3  select * from test;

     NAME1      NAME2    SALARY1    SALARY2    SALARY3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      3000     400000    8000000         90       9999
```

**Set**:

```
SQL> set numformat 999G999G990
```

**After**:

```
SQL> /

       NAME1        NAME2      SALARY1      SALARY2      SALARY3
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
       3,000      400,000    8,000,000           90        9,999

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_char to do that

if you don't want the last dor in your result you can delete it.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(8000000 , 'fm999G999G999D99')
FROM DUAL;
```

| TO_CHAR(8000000,'FM999G999G999D99') |
| --- |
| 8,000,000. |

```
SELECT 
    regexp_replace(TO_CHAR(8000000 , 'fm999G999G999D99'), '\.$', '')
FROM DUAL;
```

| REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_CHAR(8000000,'FM999G999G999D99'),'.$','') |
| --- |
| 8,000,000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aixsGO_i)